# Quartz.net get all jobs by specific job data

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

In my application i associate jobs to each user:

```
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>()
        .UsingJobData("userId", 10)
        .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .Build();
```

then i would like to get all jobs scheduled in quartz.net associated to some user of my application.

Would it be possible, or someone can suggest a solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: As i remember right, the job data has an other aim. It is to provide informations to the job execution. Why you dont use the group and job key as indicator?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do it after scheduling, we can populate a

```
List<JobDetail>
```

but I couldn't find a better way than iterating through the keys. I had to do something similar but later changed the dependency to the JobKey instead as Rabban asks.

```
var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains("group1");
var keys = await scheduler.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);    // Get all JobKeys

// Get all JobDetails
var jobDetails = new List<IJobDetail>();                                               
foreach(var key in keys)
{
    jobDetails.Add(await scheduler.GetJobDetail(key));                    
}

var userTensJobs = jobDetails.Where(j => j.JobDataMap.WrappedMap.Any(x => 
    x.Key.Equals("userId") && x.Value.Equals(10)));
```